# Node.js 0.12.0 on CentOS 6 (by rpm)

Tags: node.js, rpm, centos6

Im interested on installing the 0.12.0 version of Node.js on a CentOS 6 machine. I have noticed however that through yum, the latest version available is 0.10.33.

Given my environment I can ONLY install packages through RPM, and as I might be inclined to generate my own rpm of Node.js 0.12.0, I would like to know if there is any specific reason why the latest version has yet been made available. Are there by any chance some known problems when running the latest version of Node.js on CentOS 6? Or are there any stable 0.12.0 rpm packages out there I might have missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no problem:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/tqiKHCqpeuM

Node v0.12.0 should be stable on all versions os Centos back to 5.7